# Is it possible run query COPY TO STDOUT WITH BINARY and stream results with node-postgres?

Tags: node-postgres

I'm worried about data-type coercion or will i get a nice Buffer or UInt8Array? Can I get it in chunks (streaming)?

Answer (score -1):

Delving into npm I found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-copy-streams  -- this is the answer I was looking for.

Here is a bit more information (copied from the README) so you can avoid traversing the link:

> pg-copy-streams
>
> COPY FROM / COPY TO for node-postgres. Stream from one database to
>   another, and stuff.
>
> how? what? huh?
>
> Did you know the all powerful PostgreSQL supports streaming binary
>   data directly into and out of a table? This means you can take your
>   favorite CSV or TSV or whatever format file and pipe it directly into
>   an existing PostgreSQL table. You can also take a table and pipe it
>   directly to a file, another database, stdout, even to /dev/null if
>   you're crazy!
>
> What this module gives you is a Readable or Writable stream directly
>   into/out of a table in your database. This mode of interfacing with
>   your table is very fast and very brittle. You are responsible for
>   properly encoding and ordering all your columns. If anything is out of
>   place PostgreSQL will send you back an error. The stream works within
>   a transaction so you wont leave things in a 1/2 borked state, but it's
>   still good to be aware of.
>
> If you're not familiar with the feature (I wasn't either) you can read
>   this for some good helps:
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: small note: using COPY FROM can leave your database filled with unused data where there is an error. Don't forget to run vacuum after errors